# Can I use a meeple the turn after begging?

Tags: champions-of-midgard

In Champions of Midgard, the rules state that I can Beg with one of my meeples:

> If you find yourself unable or unwilling to activate a board location, you must Beg. To Beg, lie a worker down on your player board then take 1 Food and 1 Blame from the supply.

Can I then use that meeple on a subsequent turn (within the same worker placement phase of the current round) or is that meeple effectively placed at a location on the board and unavailable to me for the rest of the round? The meeple stays on my player board, so it seems that I would be able to use it on my next turn, but is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the second edition rules:

> During the worker placement phase, players take turns placing their workers on board locations and
>   executing their effects.

This makes it clear that workers "on board" are used. It never mentions *which* board, so that would imply that workers placed on any boards are used, and cannot perform other actions.

Also note that your "worker supply" is placed off to the side of your player board, and never directly on it. (A lot of people like doing that, hence why the "lay the worker down" language was added in the second edition rules, but officially unused workers are not on any sort of cardboard.)

The spirit of the game rules is that begging is a last resort option for someone who needs food but does not have access to it via the normal methods. It's not supposed to be an "extra" loan, and especially not to pass ones turn (which in very rare cases might have strategic value!)